# Why am I getting existence error when trying to remove doubles from a list?

Tags: prolog

Why am I getting existence error here, specifically:

```
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,list_append/2),noDoubles/2)
```

I would like to remove doubles from a list and I tried using the 'if' from prolog.

```
list_append(X,[],[X]).
list_append(X,L1,[X|L1]).

noDoubles([X],[X]).
noDoubles([H|T],L1):- (member(H,T) -> noDoubles(T,L1);(list_append(H,L1),noDoubles(T,L1))).
```

I have prolog 1.4.4

Comment: You only define `list_append/3` **but** call `list_append/2`.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined list_append with arity 3, and you're calling list_append predicate with arity 2.